# Documentation beta content

Tags: discussion, documentation

Hey I just got my documentation invite. First of all, I want to thank you for the opportunity to provide feedback.

Me and [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) are the only gold badge owners in the [promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/promise) badge in StackOverflow - with the help of [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) and some other [active](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye) we have been putting a lot of work into keeping the badge clean, answering all the answerable questions and making sure people who have interesting questions get a good user experience in StackOverflow. I think the bunch of us have accumulated knowledge both in in the topic and in answering questions about the topic.

I entered the documentation beta and I noticed there are a lot of mistakes in the [promises](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises) guide and documentation. I wanted to edit it but was immediately prompted there are two ongoing edits in the last two hours which took a lot of my screen size, I can't dismiss and I'm unsure what I should or shouldn't edit.

I submitted a small fix first to get the hang of it - but now it is being reviewed and I'm not sure if I should keep editing it.

Optimally, I'd like to be able to copy or migrate content from StackOverflow such as [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) or [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) or [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain) to documentation. It was not obvious to me how they relate to the current documentation.

In fact at this point it is so disorganized I'm tempted to start over the whole promises section and shape it "more properly". I don't want to do so because I acknowledge that this is a community and I don't want to step on peoples' toes or appear rude. I have no obvious means  I'm aware of to contact them and suggest such a drastic change (except maybe here).

What should I do about it?

I hope this post doesn't come off as rude or as a rant. I'm very unexperienced with the documentation platform. If it does - I apologize.

Comment: Ideally before editing anything you [should start here](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: In general, what s?

Comment: You appear to be very considerate. There is no topic or tag specific discussion place like the comments section here (at least I haven't found one yet). So, every discussion should happen on SO Meta. My guess is that you should start making changes and see how they are received. In the best case, people will see the benefits of your changes and will follow you. However, in case of conflicting opinions we might run into problems. Currently it's unclear how to proceed then?? This is new territory, also for StackOverflow. They never really had collaborative creation of content on such a scale.

Comment: @Trilarion Note the date on this, I think it's actually from the early private beta (not sure if it's still relevant now) Benjamin do you still need help here?

Comment: Thanks @TimPost - I think I'll just wait for things to settle with documentation before I participate.